# Jquery Validate não funciona com tipo de extensão - File Input

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery-validate

Segue o código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myform").validate({
                ignore: ":hidden",
                rules: {

                    images: { required: true, extension: "jpg"},
                    messages: { 
                    images: Arquivo inválido}
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {


                        ajax - post ....

                    }                   
            }
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="file" id="image_preview" class="form-control" name="images" accept="image/*">
```

Eu uso esse [bootstrap fileinput](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/#Downloads)

Após de escolher uma imagem, recebo erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. 
>   Exception occurred when checking element image_preview, check the
>   'extension' method.

Se eu deixar somente `"{ required: true}"` ele funciona como o campo requerido. Com o tipo de extensão não funciona.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Pode ser a versão do jQuery Validate. Baixou do site deles ?

Comment: Baixei pelo manage nuget packages

Comment: Você adicionou o `jquery.validate.methods` na página depois do `jquery.validate` ?

Comment: Eu não encontro esse nome `jquery.validate.methods` na minha pasta script. Detalhe, baixei direto pelo nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar esse tipo de validação é simples, adicione o [additional-methods.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js) junto com [jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js) e [jQuery.Validation](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js), e na sua validação inclua `extension` com os tipos que deseja verificar, no exemplo eu coloquei `jpg|jpeg|gif`, mas, isso fico ao seu critério.

*Exemplo:*

***Form***

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <div>
    <label> Digite o nome:
      <input type="text" name="tname" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label> Escolha a Foto:
      <input type="file" name="tfoto" id="tfoto" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

***Javascript***

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form1").validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
      rules: {
        tname : {
            required : true
        },
        tfoto : {
            required : true,
            extension: "jpg|jpeg|gif"
        }
      },
      messages: {
        tname : {
            required : 'Digite o nome'
        },
        tfoto : {
            required : 'Escolha a foto',
            extension: 'Foto do tipo inválida'
        }
      }
  });

  $("#tfoto").filestyle();
});
```

[***Exemplo - jsfiddle.net***](https://jsfiddle.net/rga5gxa1/)

Para adicionar a referencia no [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), faça:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
         .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*","~/Scripts/additional-methods.min.js"));
```

***Referencia:***

[Lib - jQuery.validate](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate)

Comment: Thank you :) Viriglio Novic

Comment: Coloquei na resposta !!! @MatheusMiranda